# Is there any way to see all the versions for a python package?

Tags: python

For example, from looking through the code and branch/[tag names for a package](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python) you can sometimes figure out the earliest time a version might have been released, can you do this from pypi directly? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/raven

**edit**

The desired output would be:

```
2012-03-31  0.1
2012-06-12  0.2
2013-08-22  0.3
```

Comment: What would be the desired output in case of `raven`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "All versions" link on https://warehouse.python.org/project/raven/ does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a programmatic answer.  This code lets you search PyPi for packages, and it lists all versions available.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
pversions.py -- search for package version from PyPi
'''
# adapted from pip.commands.SearchCommand

import sys, xmlrpclib

pnames = sys.argv[1:]
if not pnames:
    sys.exit('Usage: pversions (packagename)...')

pypi = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://pypi.python.org/pypi')
for packagename in (pname.lower() for pname in pnames):
    print packagename,':'
    exact_hits = (
        hit for hit in pypi.search({'name': packagename})
        if hit['name'].lower() == packagename
    )
    print ', '.join( (hit['version'] for hit in exact_hits) )
```

Example output:

```
./pversions.py django raven
django :
1.0.4, 1.1.4, 1.2.7, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5
raven :
4.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this list at https://pypi.python.org/simple/raven/. I'm not aware of any web GUI that shows this.